# Key column 'BranchNo' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

```
CREATE TABLE Staff (staffNo varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
                    FName nvarchar(20),
                    LName nvarchar(20),
                    position varchar(15),
                    gender char(1),
                    DOB datetime,
                    salary numeric(8,2),
                    FOREIGN KEY (branchNo) REFERENCES Branch);
```

I have already executed the Branch tables effectively, however when I try to execute the Staff table with the foreign key, it doesnt allow it. Thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a foreign key, the column named must be a column in the table that contains the foreign key.

```
FOREIGN KEY (branchNo) REFERENCES Branch
```

In this case, `branchNo` must be a column in the `Staff` table. But there is no column by that name in the `Staff` table you showed.

Next, MySQL requires you to name the column in the referenced table as well. Standard ANSI SQL has a shortcut that by default, the column is assumed to have the same name in the referenced table, but MySQL doesn't allow this.

So I would think something like the following would work for you:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff (
  staffNo varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  FName nvarchar(20),
  LName nvarchar(20),
  position varchar(15),
  gender char(1),
  DOB datetime,
  salary numeric(8,2),
  branchNo INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (branchNo) REFERENCES Branch(branchNo)
);
```

This shows that you must declare the column `branchNo` in addition to including it in a foreign key definition. This allows you to give the column attributes like a data type, and possibly a default or NOT NULL option.

Then you must name the column in the referenced table as well, even if the column has the same name in both tables.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Bill, I'm quite new to SQL so would you mind telling me how to name the column in the referenced table? Current expected issue I'm getting is error 3780.

Comment: @randomuser764 Never post shortened error message, always provide complete text.

Comment: @randomuser764 The most common choice  is to use the primary key column of the referenced table.

Comment: Thanks a-lot for your help, I found that I put the foreign key as INT instead of varchar which was what i previously used.

Comment: Right, they have to be the same data type in both tables.